# Preventing a function from running if a parallel function has already failed (using jQuery $.when())

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I have a rather convoluted series of asynchronous functions that I am chaining with the help of jQuery Deferreds.

Essentially I have two parallel streams of functions, followed by functions that should be executed serially when the parallel streams have both finished. Here's an example (they are AJAX calls in real life):

```
function makeOmelette() {
    $.when(
        crackEggs().then(beatEggs),
        washTomatos().then(chopTomatos)
    ).then(mixEggsAndTomatos).then(fryEggsAndTomatos).done(function() {
        msg('Omelette is ready!');
    }).fail(function() {
        msg('Oh no, omelette fail!');
    });
}
```

The `done()` and `fail()` handlers at the end deal with success or failure. I would like the `fail()` handler to execute as soon as anything goes wrong, anywhere in the chain, and for all further execution to stop.

Mostly, this works - apart from one case. If there is a failure when cracking eggs, then the tomatos are still washed and chopped - even if the failure has already occurred by the time either of those tasks have started. Similarly, if there is a failure when washing tomatos, this doesn't stop the crackEggs and beatEggs functions from running.

You can see [an example here](https://jsfiddle.net/9Nykw/).

My concern about this is that, in my real life code, I don't want the browser to be making AJAX calls to the server, which could potentially change state, if there is no point because the overall process has already failed.

Is there a way to do what I want? I suppose I could attach fail handlers to each of the parallel tasks individually, but I wondered if there was a less verbose/repetitive way.

Thanks!

Comment: "Mostly, this works - apart from one case. If there is a failure when cracking eggs, then the tomatos are still washed and chopped" . Is requirement that if error at `crackEggs()` , `washTomatos()` does not proceed ? Thanks

Comment: If an error has already occurred during `crackEggs()` by the time that `washTomatos()` is due to start, then `washTomatos()` should not be executed. And the same goes for any of the parallel tasks - if a failure has occurred before the task starts, then the task should not be executed. So it's more of a general requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a variable to the statuses. eg inside of `done( var status = 1 )` and inside of `fail( var status = 2` then put a simple statement before the running of the parallel function so that it won't run if `status = 2`.

Comment: I'm inclined to think that this is the answer, i.e. there is no built-in mechanism with promises/deferreds that handles this, so the developer has to handle it themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Try (this pattern)

html

```
<input type="button" value="reject" />
<input type="button" value="resolve" /> <output></output> <output></output>
<div id="messages"></div>
```

js

```
$(function () {
    $("input").on("click", function (e) {
        var dfd = new $.Deferred();

        $("#messages").children().remove();
        makeOmelette(this.value);

        function makeOmelette(resolveReject, dfd) {
            // dfd = dfd;
            $.when(
            // `crackEggs("resolve")`, `crackEggs("reject")`
            crackEggs(resolveReject), 
            washTomatos())
                .done(function (a, b) {
                if (a === "rejected") {
                    err();
                };
                if (a === "resolved") {
                    beatEggs();
                    chopTomatos();
                    mixEggsAndTomatos();
                    fryEggsAndTomatos();
                    success();
                };

            });
        };

        function success() {
            dfd.done(function (s) {
                msg('Omelette is ready!');
                $("output:first").val(s);
            })
        };

        function err() {
            dfd.fail(function (e) {
                msg('Oh no, omelette fail!');
                $("output:first").val(e);
            });
        };

        dfd.always(function () {
            $("output:last").val(dfd.state() + " at " + $.now())
        });

        function crackEggs(_resolveReject) {
            (_resolveReject === "reject" 
             ? dfd.reject(_resolveReject + " called at " + $.now()) 
             : dfd.resolve(_resolveReject + " called at " + $.now())
            );
            msg('Cracking eggs');
            return dfd.state();
        }

        function beatEggs() {
            msg('Beating eggs');
            return dfd.state();
        }

        function washTomatos() {
            msg('Washing tomatos');
            return dfd.state();
        }

        function chopTomatos() {
            msg('Chopping tomatos');
            return dfd.state();
        }

        function mixEggsAndTomatos() {
            msg('Mixing eggs and tomatos');
            return dfd.state();
        }

        function fryEggsAndTomatos() {
            msg('Frying eggs and tomatos');
            return dfd.state();
        }

        function msg(text) {
            $('#messages').append('<p>' + text + '</p>');
        }
    });
});
```

JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/WWF68/